# python quits unexpectedly when using locals() or globals()

Tags: python, cmd

In a project that I was working on, I needed to go in and out from the interpreter constantly and I got bored of the key combination `ctrl+z+enter`. So I created a shortcut to exit faster from the python terminal with just two keys (from cmd), but it causes the interpreter to quit. Consider the following code inside of the file `lazy.py`:

```
class hotkey():
     def __repr__(self):
          exit()
          return ''

q = hotkey()
```

The problem arises when I use `from lazy import *` and then try to use either `locals()` or `globals()`. But if `q` is not directly in the scope, e. g. using `import lazy`, both of them work as expected, but the point of the module was to be able to just using `q+enter` and not `lazy.q+enter`.

I gave up and returned to `ctrl+z` but not knowing the reason for this is subtracting my hours of sleep. Any idea of what could be going on?

Comment: Why, oh why, are you using **`__repr__`** for side effects???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga don't worry. It is just part of my `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable and, when I need to test or run a project, it is always in an isolated space. I'm not here to spread bad practices hahaha. `ctrl+z` seems to do other actions in other OS, but in windows, it is equivalent to `exit()`, or that's what the interpreter recommends when you type `exit` and forget about the `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to figure this out.  Try printing `globals()` without your import.  Notice that each variable is listed along with its representation.  When it tries to fetch the representation for `q`, your code will exit the interpreter.

You must be on Windows.  Remember that you can keep a separate console open with your interpreter; you don't have to exit.  Also, if you `pip install readline`, then Ctrl-D and Ctrl-Z will exit the interpreter without the Enter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `readline` has been distributed with CPython for a while. Out of curiosity, what does Ctrl - Z do in a windows CMD shell? I'm guessing it isn't SIGSTOP like in *Nix?

Comment: No, it's end-of-file -- the equivalent of Ctrl-D on Linux.  That is literally a carry over from CP/M.  And I don't believe `readline` is distributed with Python on Windows.  The behavior changes when it is installed.

Comment: I suspected that it could be simple, but I never got through my head that possibility. With some friends, we were talking about it. None of us could get an answer too. In their name and mine, thank you so much, Tim! Now I can sleep in peace.

Comment: I believe the suggested alternative these days is `pyreadline`.

Comment: I believe @Selcuk is right.  It's been a while, and I forgot.